# magento 2 connection elastic server takes times to connect

Tags: magento2.4, performance, elasticsearch

Is anyone know why sometime elastic server takes time to connect

Here is the screenshot from New relic report

This screenshot report generated when customer visiting product listing pages.

[image]

Is this server issue where we are hosted? or is it need to increase a plan or specifically Magento issue?

Answer (score 0):

Improve cluster performance, including optimizing queries, monitoring resource usage, adjusting shard configurations, and implementing appropriate indexing strategies.

Comment: thank you for your answer, i have resolve issue by upgrade elastic search  server plan

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue by upgrade elastic server plan